# Flutter - How to do an infinite card feed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display one by one each document of a collection from Firestore. A document is a card containing an image and a text with a button to show the next card. Basically, my app should have the same behavior as Tinder: display one card then the next one, and never twice the same.

At the moment, I made a StreamBuilder that call the last 10 cards in a Stack so each card is on top of each other (hiding the next one).
But with this solution I have 2 problems :

- I don't know how to display the next item when the user tap on the
  next button. The current card has to disappear to let the next one being visible.
- The StreamBuilder call only 10 cards, I would like to load 10 more
  cards when the user is almost at the end (at the card number 8 for
  example) so the user don't even realize the loading in the background.

Maybe the StreamBuilder is not the solution at all. But I have no idea what is the best way to do it.

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: firestore.collection('Feed').orderBy('date').limit(10).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          var _docs = snapshot.data.docs;
          if (_docs.isEmpty)
            return Center(
              child: Text("There is no more cards"),
            );
          return Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
              children: _docs.map((document) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: CardItem(...),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          );
        });
```

Comment: use listview.builder widget and inside of it return stack

Comment: Could you tell me a bit more please?